# Angular 4 error when navigating using secondary outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an issue with navigation using a secondary outlet.

- I have a LayoutComponent which is loaded into the primary router-outlet.
- The LayoutComponent contains a secondary outlet named `content-outlet`

So far everything is fine and I am able to navigate to e.g. `/accounts/1/overview` and have the `content-outlet` load the correct component (OverviewComponent). But when I click the link in the sidebar to navigate to the `/accounts/1/stats` route I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
```

The same thing happens if I first navigate to `/accounts/1/stats` and then try to activate `/accounts/1/overview`.

The LayoutComponent:

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="topbar-content-wrapper">
  <app-topbar></app-topbar>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet name="content-outlet"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

The sidebar navigation:

```
<a href="#" [routerLink]="[ '/accounts', accountId, 'overview' ]">Overview</a>
<a href="#" [routerLink]="[ '/accounts', accountId, 'stats' ]">Stats</a>
```

The Routes:

```
{
path: 'accounts/:accountid',
component: LayoutComponent,
canActivate: [AuthService],
children: [
  {
    path: 'stats',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: StatsComponent,
        outlet: 'content-outlet'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'overview',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: OverviewComponent,
        outlet: 'content-outlet'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: why do you have href="#" on the navbar links?

Comment: I don't think it matters? @Jota.Toledo

Answer (score 0):

change your routes to the following

```
{
   path: 'accounts/:accountid',
   component: LayoutComponent,
   canActivate: [AuthService],
},
{
    path: 'stats',
    component: StatsComponent,
    outlet: 'content-outlet'
 },
{
    path: 'overview',
    component: OverviewComponent,
    outlet: 'content-outlet'
}
```

and your sidebar navigation links too:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { content-outlet: ['overview'] } }]">Overview</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { content-outlet: ['stats'] } }]">Stats</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. When I change the Routes definition to your suggestion I can no longer navigate to the page at all. I get an error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'accounts/1/overview'`and get redirected to my default route `/login`

Comment: I really don't think you can have the secondary outlet components nested inside the root outlet components in your routes definition because each named outlet should have its own set of routes with their own components. check my updated answer to see what I mean.

Comment: But it works nicely until I have to change what component is loaded into the `content-outlet`?